# Is there a web site (and/or) the book(s)in which are accumulated theories/ideas from science fiction & fantasy books/movies?

Tags: fantasy-genre, science-fiction-genre, online-resources

I'm searching for sites and/or books which have the most interesting theories (pseudo-theories), philosophical/religious ideas, and hypotheses gathered from speculative fiction, primarily, in science fiction and fantasy. For example, the movie *The Matrix* (1999) has some interesting (pseudo)theories.

Also, web sites which trace the origins of ideas/hypotheses, motifs (leitmotifs) in movies (primarily animation) and/or literature would be very useful. For example, the movie *The Matrix*, has ideas from philosophy, religion, Japanese animation, and *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*.

I'm also wondering how many other people are interested in this, too.

Comment: Questions asking for lists of things are considered off-topic here, sorry.

Comment: I didn't ask for a/the list.

Answer (score 5):

[Technovelgy](http://www.technovelgy.com/) would probably satisfy part of your request - it's a directory of technologies proposed in fiction with information about who proposed it. I can't speak to the completeness of it.

Answer (score 2):

For books discussing the inspirations, philosophy, influences etc. of a particular work, it would be best to look at companion books to that work - for example, if you're interested in Neil Gaiman's *Sandman* series, Hy Bender's *The Sandman Companion* is worth a look.

An overview of such facets of *all* Science Fiction would be way beyond the scope of any single work, but the Clute/Nicholls [Encyclopedia of Science Fiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Encyclopedia_of_Science_Fiction) is as good an overview of the field as any.

Comment: 'Beyond the scope of any single work'?  My friend, I give you [TV Tropes](http://www.tvtropes.org)

Comment: Speaking of the Encyclopedia of Science Fiction, the third edition will be online (since a print edition would be far far too big) and the beta text is available now: http://sf-encyclopedia.com/

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to your question, yet you might want to take a look at [*A History of Science Fiction*, a special map](http://bigthink.com/ideas/31662)  by Ward Shelley. (This link leads to a website that provides a great introduction to the map. From there, you'll have to follow another link to arrive at [the actual map](http://www.wardshelley.com/paintings/pages/HistoryofScienceFiction.html) (click "enlarge here" in the upper right corner.))